# Find actual location of installed python app. (not the symlink)

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the location of my python app.  But when I try it always returns the location of my symlink.

For example:
My app in stalled at /opt/mth/lib/processor/proc
I have a symlink at /opt/mth/bin/proc

When I run the following code:

```
import os.path
import sys

def path():
    return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

My function always returns the path to /opt/mth/bin  which is my symlink.

How can I get the actual path?  I need it because I have configuration files at the actual path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
os.path.realpath(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That got me almost there.  I actually had to do: 

    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.executable))